# Interaction between xaml and xaml.cs files within same namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 <Window x:Class="logf.Circles"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Circles" Height="426" Width="581" Name="Cir">
    <Grid Background="Beige">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="myfirst">
              <Setter Property="Height" Value="150" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
            </Style>


        </Grid.Resources>
        <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource myfirst}" Fill="red"  Name="ellipse1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource myfirst}" Fill="Orange"  Name="ellipse2" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource myfirst}" Fill="green"  Name="ellipse3" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <Button Content="Replace" Name="button1" Tag="c_replace" ToolTip="To replace color" Margin="100" Click="button1_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>


</Window>
```

The above is my xaml code for circles.xaml

I am new to WPF and wanted to ask something which might even be really silly. I created a xaml file and wanted to use it in MainWindow.xaml.cs file. But ,I get an error saying that

> "The type or namespace name 'filename' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

How to do the interaction between `.xaml and .xaml.cs` file within same class. Thanks.

Comment: You should post your code and show your try before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

In your `mainwindow.xaml.cs` you should run the `InitializeComponent()` for the new `xaml` page you created.

So just running `var MyNewXamlWindow = new MyNewXaml();`  method in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` should call the initialise code here at make the page available for you

```
public MyNewXaml()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

For your case replace MyNewXaml with Circles