# Windows Phone 8.1 Unable to Recognize the Page Being Navigated to

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

On a Windows Phone 8.1 app, I am trying to pass data from MainPage page to ImageFullScreen page. I am passing the data from a .shared file (MainPage.cs), but it is not recognizing the ImageFullScreen page. Am I missing something?

```
public class PassedData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void ListItems_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(ImageFullScreen), new PassedData { Name = "my name"});        
}
```

Error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ImageFullScreen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Right click on where it says imagefullscreen, do you have an option to import anything? I'm curious if your namespace is different.

Comment: @Adam Tuliper-MSFT, I do not have that option...

Comment: look into your ImageFullScreen, is it the same namespace? if so see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516731/interaction-between-xaml-and-xaml-cs-files-within-same-namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the namespace of your view `(ImageFullScreen)` in the page.

> using App1.Views;

Where

`App1` is your Project Name

`Views` is your folder name where your ImageFullScreen.xaml file placed.

And if ImageFullScreen.xaml is created directly inside your project, use

> using App1;